# Android: How to group a textview and imageview in a checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview

I want to design a checkbox look like this:

[image: Example]

I can do it on html with table.
But I have no idea how to work on android.
Please give me some hint!

Comment: Maybe you could try with a RealtiveLayout. This is the way to customize it like a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />

   <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
          />
  <ImageView android:id="+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks your hint! I did it!